# How do I add a 32bit/64bit reference file based on Platform in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, wix, visual-studio-2019, manifest, 32bit-64bit

I'm trying to build a project and based on the platform I'm building in, I want a reference file to be added from the allocated location.

When I build in x86, I want the program to use the file located in the `\bin`. And the `\bin_x64` folder when I build in x64.

Similar to these posts

- [Conditionally use 32/64 reference when building in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832552/conditionally-use-32-64-bit-reference-when-building-in-visual-studio)
- [Targeting both 32bit and 64bit with visual studio in the same solution/project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145803/targeting-both-32bit-and-64bit-with-visual-studio-in-same-solution-project)

I've added a .manifest file in my project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <assemblyIdentity name="DriverLib" processorArchitecture="*" type="win32" version="1.0.0.0"/>
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="DriverLib" processorArchitecture="x86" type="win32" version="1.0.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="DriverLib" processorArchitecture="amd64" type="win32" version="1.0.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>
</assembly>
```

In file structure below, I have to manually add the DriverLib reference file from the `\bin`. Which is not ideal and caused errors when I run using the 64bit platform.

[image]

In the project file, I've added the conditions

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x64'">
    <WixLibrary Include="DriverLib">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Bin_x64\DriverLib.wixlib</HintPath>
      <Name>DriverLib</Name>
    </WixLibrary>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup  Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86'">
    <WixLibrary Include="DriverLib">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Bin\DriverLib.wixlib</HintPath>
        <Name>DriverLib</Name>
    </WixLibrary>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Is there a way to have it were by if I run in platform x86, the correct reference file gets added, and then if I run in x64, the `DriverLib.wixlib` for the 32bit is replaced with the 64bit file?

**UPDATE**

I believe I've narrowed down the problem. The file does add when I run it, but when I run it in 64bit it does not replace the file with the file in the `\bin_x64` folder. If I change the directory in the `<ItemGroup>` condition for the x86 item to the `\bin_x64`, it will then add the file. So somehow it is not using the 64bit `<ItemGroup>`. I also tried changing the order of them and placing the condition in the `<WixLibrary>` tags, as suggested in the post below.

Something similar to this post:

- [.csproj Platform specific ItemGroup works for assembly references but not for content includes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470308/csprojs-platform-specific-itemgroup-works-for-assembly-references-but-not-cont)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having a similar issue, well turns out it was pulling in the correct reference, it just did not show the correct path in the properties. However when I searched through the output after the build, it was indeed grabbing the reference file from the allocated location.

The .manifest file did nothing, so I deleted that, all that is needed for this to work is the `<ItemGroup>` conditions in the .csproj file and it should use the reference file you want even if it does not update the location in properties.